# ODATA Filtering on DateTimeOffset

Tags: datetimeoffset, odata4j

I'm trying to filter on a DateTimeOffset (myDate in the examples below).
Since I want to ignore the time part, I believe the only way to filter is to compare separately the year, month and day components e.g.

```
...entities?$filter=year(myDate) eq 2013
```

This is also in accordance with the ODATA spec:
http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-v3-documentation/url-conventions/#512412_year

The problem is... it just does not work:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: unsupported expression YearMethodCallExpression&#xd; 
at org.odata4j.producer.jpa.JPQLGenerator.toJpql(JPQLGenerator.java:187)&#xd;
at org.odata4j.producer.jpa.JPQLGenerator.binaryCommonExpressionToJpql(JPQLGenerator.java:309)&#xd;
at org.odata4j.producer.jpa.JPQLGenerator.toJpql(JPQLGenerator.java:192)&#xd;
at org.odata4j.producer.jpa.GenerateJPQLCommand.generateJPQL(GenerateJPQLCommand.java:121)&#xd  ;
at org.odata4j.producer.jpa.GenerateJPQLCommand.execute(GenerateJPQLCommand.java:34)&#xd;
at org.odata4j.producer.jpa.Chain.execute(Chain.java:29)&#xd;
at org.odata4j.producer.jpa.JPAProducer.getEntities(JPAProducer.java:278)&#xd;
```

If I use the filter below then I don't get any error, but it's not what I want to do because the time part in myDate is never midnight (T00:00:00.000Z) so the equality always results in a False:

```
...entities?$filter=myDate eq datetimeoffset'2013-09-30T00:00:00.000Z'
```

Any idea?
Many thanks!

Comment: Did you implement that year canonical function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A workaround for this issue is to use the following two filters:

...entities?$filter=myDate ge datetimeoffset'2013-09-30T00:00:00.000Z' and myDate lt datetimeoffset'2013-10-30T00:00:00.000Z'

I still don't understand why the year/month/day functions don't work though.

Comment: when did this happen? is it because of the lib version?

Comment: This works for OData **v2** `datetimeoffset'2013-10-30T00:00:00.000Z'` is the crux. `year()` conversion didn't work for me on **v2**.